# Debug/Improve Performance of GRASS v.in.ogr

Tags: grass-gis, ogr, performance

I'm trying to import shapefiles (in this case, OpenStreetMap data) into GRASS (grass70-svn) using `v.in.ogr`; and it is painfully, brutally slow. At first I thought this was because I was using the default sqlite database on an NFS mount. But, trying sqlite on a local disk and trying MySQL to separate server both failed to improve performance. I'm getting a consistent read/write of ~125Kbps/~550Kbps no matter which shapefile or which database I use.

I cannot see any bottlenecks anywhere, as the two `python /path/to/grass-gui` processes are averaging 10% of one core combined, the network utilization is below 10% consistently, and the DB server is almost quiescent. To give an example of how painful this is:

```
v.in.ogr dsn=/home/justin/downloads/osm_CA/places.shp                           
WARNING: All available OGR layers will be imported into vector map <places>
Check if OGR layer <places> contains polygons...
Importing 7020 features (OGR layer <places>)...
-----------------------------------------------------
Building topology for vector map <places@OSM>...
Registering primitives...
7020 primitives registered
7020 vertices registered
Building areas...
0 areas built
0 isles built
Attaching islands...
Attaching centroids...
Number of nodes: 0
Number of primitives: 7020
Number of points: 7020
Number of lines: 0
Number of boundaries: 0
Number of centroids: 0
Number of areas: 0
Number of isles: 0
(Fri Jan 31 19:01:08 2014) Command finished (4 min 38 sec)
```

Any guidance on how to remediate this problem, or at least find the bottleneck? I'm stumped.

Comment: What is your OS, Linux, Mac OS X, and  your grass70-svn  came from where ? I don't have any problem to import osm shapefiles (> 10000 features) within seconds (local SQLite)

Comment: Did you check: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Debugging?

Answer (score 1):

For the record here: Discussion continued here:

http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/2185#comment:2